# Excel VBA: specify which charts to edit with macro

Tags: vba, excel

I already wrote macro that edit one chart.
Now I would like to edit many charts at once, for example all this charts:

- "chart 15"
- "chart 18"
- "chart 22"
- "chart 27"
- "chart 85"
- "chart 55"
- etc...

How can I do that without copying pasting "edit-Chart-Code" under each:

for example:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 15").Activate
```

Comment: loop through desired charts and call that "edit-chart-code" each time

Comment: Please add the code you already have tried to achieve this.

Comment: [This is Microsoft's information about utilizing vba to target charts.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-object-excel)

Comment: i don know how to loop, so i wrote 2 macros,

Comment: first is:  
          Sub DOL()
'
' DOL Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 204").Activate
    Call Macro21
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 207").Activate
    Call Macro21
    End With
 
    End With
       

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If these are the chart names on the active sheet, and you're always going to do them all, then something like this might help:

```
Sub FormatNamedCharts()
  Dim chob As ChartObject

  For Each chob In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Select Case chob.Name
      Case "Chart 15", "Chart 18", "Chart 22", "Chart 27", "Chart 85", "Chart 55"
        ' Do your
        ' formatting
        ' in here
      Case Else
        ' skip
    End Select
  Next
End Sub
```

If you want to let the user select charts to process, then this is how to do it:

```
Sub FormatSelectedCharts()
  Dim sh As Shape

  If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
    For Each sh In Selection.ShapeRange
      If sh.HasChart Then
        With sh.Chart
          ' Do your
          ' formatting
          ' in here
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```